# React router is not installing on my Windows machine

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, cmd, npm-install

This is the command that I ran to install react-router :-

```
npm install --save react-router
```

This is the output shown by my prompt window :-

```
npm WARN @babel/plugin-bugfix-v8-spread-parameters-in-optional-chaining@7.15.4 requires a peer of @babel/core@^7.13.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN tsutils@3.21.0 requires a peer of typescript@>=2.8.0 || >= 3.2.0-dev || >= 3.3.0-dev || >= 3.4.0-dev || >= 3.5.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-beta || >= 3.7.0-dev || >= 3.7.0-beta but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@2.3.2 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.3.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.13 (node_modules\watchpack-chokidar2\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.13 (node_modules\webpack-dev-server\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

+ react-router@5.2.1
updated 1 package and audited 1960 packages in 20.878s

148 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 3 moderate severity vulnerabilities
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
```

Please help me to resolve this.

Comment: With the above message stated, its clear that its installed. Check dependencies in your package.json file.

Comment: Thanks. It's there in the dependencies. Actually I am a beginner in it.

Answer (score 0):

`npm i install-peers -D`

You can use this to install peer dependencies.

I was having the same issues it worked out for me.